# Difference between native html5 video player and any other

Tags: javascript, css, html

I was [reading html5 video tutorial](http://www.html5trends.com/tutorials/implement-html5-video-support-in-5-easy-steps/) which suggested to use some player for html5 `<video>` tag such as JW player, Projektor, videojs, etc.

I know even if I don't use a player such as these, a player is drawn (in supported browsers) when using `<video>` tag.

So what exactly is difference between or pros and cons of third party player (for example [videojs player](http://videojs.com/)) over native html5 player ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The promise of HTML5 video at least to me, is avoiding all this horrible Flash setup and Javascript, and making the **browser do all the heavy lifting**.

Unfortunately using something *simple* like:

```
<video controls src="http://static.natalian.org/2012-01-18/MVI_0123.ogg" />
```

Is not enough. You are missing features like hooking into the [fullscreen API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aFullScreenAPI) which is different across browsers and hence you probably need to rely on these 3rd party libraries to take away the pain.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious one is that you'll have more control over how it looks--you'll be able to have it match your site's design.

Also, it makes sure your site looks consistent in different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I could think of is UI consistency across browsers. Every browser implements their video player differently so something like JW Player makes it look and feel the same.

Comment: Or you can implement your own custom controls via CSS and the Media API.